# How to separate a column of directory paths and create a new column with the first level directory in r

Tags: r

I have a df with 3 columns. The second column contains directory paths. How do I separate the first level directory of the path and create a new column for it?

The df looks like this:

file_path                    file_name
/owner1/project1/third         name1.bam
/owner2/project2/hard/fourth   name2.bam
/owner2/project3/easy/         name3.bam
/owner3/project4/A.            name4.bam

The output I seek is:

owner.     file_path.            file_name.    f
/owner1   /project1/third.       name1.bam
/owner2   /project2/hard/fourth. name2.bam
/owner2.  /project3/easy.        name3.bam
/owner3.  /project4/A.           name4.bam

I have tried "mutate", but when I use the "/" as the separator, it splits all the levels. All I want is to separate the first level of the path. Is there another approach or function that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 library(stringr)     
 
 df <- data.frame(lvl = c("levela1/levela2/levela3",
                     "levelb1/levelb2/levelb3",
                     "levelc1/levelc2/levelc3"))

 df <- cbind(str_split_fixed(df$lvl, '/', n=2), df[,-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me what you're looking to do precisely but you may want to try using strsplit(x, split = "/") and then index the output.

Edit:

Hey Lou_A, maybe the follwing is what you are looking. There are probably more elegant ways of doing this but this is what came to mind.

```
df <- data.frame(lvl = c("levela1/levela2/levela3",
                         "levelb1/levelb2/levelb3",
                         "levelc1/levelc2/levelc3"))

df[,"lvl1"] <- sapply(strsplit(df[,1], "/"), `[`, 1)

rep.fun <- function(str){
              lvl1 = strsplit(str, "/")[[1]][1]
              low.lvl = gsub(lvl1, "", str)
              return(low.lvl)
}

df[,"rest.lvl"] <- sapply(df[,1], rep.fun)
```

Comment: It's close, but not exactly what I need.  say I have a string: "/levelA/levelB/levelC" and all I want is to separate "/levelA" into a separate vector/column and leave "/levelB/levelC" as is.  If I use. strsplit(), it will not only split each level, but it will remove the "/" which I don't want to do.  I don't mind removing "/" from levelA, but I do want to leave it for "/levelB/levelC".  I don't think strsplit() has a way to stop the split action after the second separator encounter.

Comment: I did, however, find a variation provided by the package "stringr" that would do the trick.

Comment: stringr() works on a string.  I can't figure out how to apply it to an entire column of a data frame.   The resulting df would then contain 4 columns instead of 3 once I split the column that contains the path into two columns, one that contains the original level 1 of the path "/level1", and the other column contains the remainder of the path, "/level2/level3/..."

Comment: Does the edited answer meet your needs?

Comment: Not quite the way you wrote it, but it did point me in the right direction.  See my solution above using the function str-split-fixed() from the stringr package which allows me to select n= to equal whatever times I want to split the original df.  The solution does remove the column label and creates a label for each of the new columns, but does are easy to rename.  Thanks -monkeymind.